# Como tener los datos de una consulta inner join que tiene varias columnas?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

Tengo la siguiente inquietud, soy novato con springdata y tengo que hacer una consultar inner join la cual va ha atraer datos de 2 tablas de una base de datos. Aqui es donde quisiera saber como obtener estos datos y mapearlos, ya que por ejemplo:

En la primera tabla voy a sacar cantidad, precio, iva, total y subtotal, y en la segunda tabla solo el nombre de un producto y para mapear en los modelos necesitaría llenar todos los campos creo que así funciona como hago esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el segundo modelo seria este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta en la consulta que quiero hacer de solo estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que podria hacer ? tengo que mapear los datos ? o tendria que hacer otro objecto ? o podria mandarlos datos directos como resultado ?

Answer (score 1):

Respondo esta pregunta por si alguien mas se llega a topar con algo parecido, bueno la cuestión es que necesitaba hacer un join en utilizando JPA para sacar una consulta de 2 tablas entonces no me realizaba ninguna relacion al momento de poner la consulta en query native creo que es por la relacion de entidad como dice el compañero que me respondio pero podemos obtener estos datos a traves de tuple como son 2 entidades diferentes no se puede sacar el inner join y tuple nos ayuda con esa opcion de poder agarrar los datos de diferentes tablas y ponerlas en un solo objecto.

Si no llego hacer claro y estas buscando como mostrar los datos de un inner join la respuesta esta en Tuple. Si quieres un ejemplo te dejo el siguiente link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GR2i6dQoL_I&t=1430s&ab_channel=IsmaelRobles

Tambien dejo como quedo mi respuesta o como yo solucione ni pequeño problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la consulta utilizo tuple de persistence y cambio el tipo de retorno del dao y la implementación.

Nota: en la consulta tengo el id fijo pero posterior pues se lo asignare por url

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí voy por cada detalle, para verificar si esta mostrando los datos correctos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui en consola podemos ver son los datos que estoy buscando.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes especificar que deseas hacer con los datos y dar más contexto.

Bueno para traer los datos debes usar el repositorio y este va a asociado a un objeto que contendrá los datos que necesitas (Este objeto será una entidad).

----- DTO -----

```java
@Entity
public class HistorialVentaProductoDTO{
                    @Column(name = "cantidad")
                    private long cantidad;
                    @Column(name = "precio")
                    private int precio;
                    @Column(name = "nombre")
                    private String nombre;
                    @Column(name = "total")
                    private int total;
                    @Column(name = "iva")
                    private int iva;
                
                    // Métodos getter y setter de cada atributo
}
```

------ interface del repositorio -----

```java
@Repository
public interface HistorialVentaProductoRepository extends JpaRepository<HistorialVentaProductoDTO, Long> {
    // Aquí hacer consultas sql usando el repositorio, pero si gusta más detalle en tus consultas puedes usar JPQL 
}
```

Así que ahí en tu Capa Services haces referencia de este repositorio y después en Controller hacer referencia a la Capa Services.